# Symfony hacer una llamada a un controlador (API REST)

Tags: php, apache, symfony3, nginx, symfony

Buenas , tengo un entorno con symfony3 instalado y mi intención es hacer una api rest , uso como servidor web NGINX y como proxy reverse apache , es decir en el puerto 80 tengo NGINX y en el puerto 8080 Apache.

He desarrollado un proyecto de pruebas con Symfony3.3 y si ejecuto el comando por consola para ver las rutas veo lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El controlador lo tengo creado de esta forma

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Api\v1;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;


class UsuariosController extends Controller
{
 /**
  * @Route("/api/v1/nombre")
  * @Method("POST")
  */
 public function nombreAction(Request $request)
 {
    $nombre = $request->get('nombre');
    return new response('its ok',201);
 }
}
```

El fichero de rutas en formato yml es este

```
app:
 resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
 type: annotation
oneup_uploader:
resource: .
type: uploader
```

Ahora el problema lo tengo al intentar ejecutar esta función del controlador con el método POST para ello haciendo uso de POSTMAN hago una llamada a http://127.0.0.1:8080/portalX/api/v1/nombre?nombre=222

Pero obtengo un codigo de error 404
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: ¿Ya verificaste con debug:router si ese path se registró con éxito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La petición que estás haciendo parece que es al entorno de producción, por lo general /app_dev.php es para el entorno de desarollo y /app.php para producción. Si omites el controlador frontal el comportamiento por defecto  en el [.htaccess](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/ef617ab1de7bd664a081516ac01aca462122edb8/web/.htaccess#L6) es ir al entorno de PROD.

Las rutas en Symfony se cachean en producción por tanto si has añadido la ruta pero no has limpiado la caché esta no será accesible.

Para comprobar si la ruta es accesible en PROD puedes hacer "php bin/console debug:router --env=prod", sin embargo durante el desarrollo es mucho más sencillo usar http://127.0.0.1:8080/portalX/app_dev.php/api/v1/nombre?nombre=222

En cuanto a la API te recomiendo usar [API Plataform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/getting-started) es una distribución de Symfony con todo lo necessario para la api ya preparado.